# java mockito: is there a way to fake a class that doesnt exists?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I want to fake a new type of class that doesnt exist which implements an interface

is this possible?

for example, i have an interface

```
public interface Worker {
    boolean execute(Job c);
}
```

I have a class

```
public class CompositeWorker implements Worker {
    private List<Worker> childWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<boolean> execute(Job j){
        return childWorkers.stream().map(w -> w.execute(j)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    public addWorker(Worker worker) {
        childWorkers.add(worker)
    }
}
```

To test:

```
public class CompositeWorkerTest {
    private CompositeWorker worker;

    @BeforeMethod
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        worker = new CompositeWorker();
    }

    @Test
    test_worker() {
         Worker worker_A = mock(Worker.class);
         Worker worker_A = mock(Worker.class);
         Job job = mock(Job.class);
         when(worker_A.execute(job)).thenReturn(true);
         when(worker_B.execute(job)).thenReturn(true);
         worker.add(worker_A);
         worker.add(worker_b);
         List<boolean> results = worker.execute(job);
         //assert results contains true
    }
```

is there a way to fake/change `Worker worker_A = mock(Worker.class);` to `FakeWorker fakeWorker = mock(FakeWorker.class)` which implements Worker but it doesnt actually exists

by NOT exists, i mean there is no definition for:

```
public class FakeWorker implement Worker
```

the reason why I want to mock a different class is because Worker Type is unique

```
public addWorker(Worker worker) {
    childWorkers = childWorkers.stream().filter(w -> w.getClass() != worker.getClass())
                                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    childWorkers.add(worker)
}
```

Comment: you can define a private class in the test

Comment: @jonathanHeindl yep that would be my alternative if i cant just do it via mockito

Comment: why do you need a different class ? why not just overwrite all the methods (Mockito.spy creates a mock thats just like the original class but mockable) so it doesnt return null as default

Comment: @ealeon, Can you explain why you want to mock a class that doesn't exist? There might be other ways to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidV just updated the question. its because addWorker has a check so i can never simulate more than one type in the test

Answer (score 1):

First, chose names that make clear what's the system under test (sut) and what are mocked dependencies! Also, when using the *.initMocks()* method you don't need to call *Mockito.mock()* in many cases, just annotate class members as *@Mock!* In your case though I would recommend to create nested classes extending Worker in your test class:

```
public class CompositeWorkerTest {

  interface WorkerA extends Worker {};
  interface WorkerB extends Worker {};

  @Mock
  WorkerA workerAMock;

  @Mock
  WorkerB workerBMock;

  @Mock
  Job jobMock;

  // systemm under test
  private CompositeWorker sut;

  @BeforeMethod
  void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sut = new CompositeWorker();
  }

  @Test
  void test_worker() {
     when(workerAMock.execute(jobMock)).thenReturn(true);
     when(workerBMock.execute(jobMock)).thenReturn(true);

     sut.add(workerAMock);
     sut.add(workerBMock);

     List<boolean> results = sut.execute(jobMock);

     //assert results contains true
  }
}
```